# Analysis of general solution of an ODE2

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given ODE is: $$y''+5y'+4y= e^{-x^2}\cos(x), \forall x \in [0,\infty)$$
I need to determine:

1. Boundedness of $y(x)$
2. $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)$

I tried to solve the ODE using the method of variation of parameters and by reducing it to normal form, but it did not help. Is there a way to analyze this ODE qualitatively without actually finding the solution?

Kindly suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is VoP? ${}{}$

Comment: @copper.hat Variation of parameter method.

Comment: Show that the system is BIBO stable and that the unforced system is asymptotically (exponential here) stable.

Comment: @Moo I could not proceed with the integral. I would probably get an error function in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will be continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.  So, to show boundedness, you just need to examine as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

As $x \rightarrow \infty$, the RHS approaches zero.  Can you say anything about the boundedness of the solution to
$$y_{\infty}''+5y_{\infty}'+4y_{\infty} = 0?$$

Hint:  What are the eigenvalues?

---

Why should this work?  We can analyze the formula for the particular solution from VOP.
$$y_p(x) = -e^{-x}\int \frac{e^{-4x}g(x)}{W(e^{-x},e^{-4x})}dx+e^{-4x}\int \frac{e^{-x}g(x)}{W(e^{-x},e^{-4x})}dx.$$

Without trying to perform the integrals, we can dominate each integrand by the integral with $g(x) = e^{-x^2}\cos(x)$ replaced by the number $1$, since the RHS is less than $1$ for $x>0$.

Then, show that both integrals converge over $[0,\infty]$ with $g$ replaced with $1$.  In fact, the RHS could be any function that approaches $0$ in the limit and this argument will work.  If the integrals over all of $\mathbb{R^+}$ converge, the integrals will be finite over any interval $[0,x]$.
This tells us both integrals are bounded in absolute value, which is why we only need the solutions to the homogeneous problem to be bounded.

Comment: +1 for the solution. A tiny typo in the second integral, the integrand part is $e^{-x}$ in stead of $e^{-4x}$